# While parsing email Getting exception "Media Type must be in the format type "/" subtype Parameter name: mediaType"

Tags: exception, media-type, openpop, email-parsing

My project parse email through `OpenPop library`. 
Every time mail from specific sender is not parsing and getting following exception

> Message: Media Type must be in the format type "/" subtype Parameter
>   name: mediaType Source: OpenPop TargetSite: System.String
>   cleanMediaType(System.String) StackTrace: at
>   OpenPop.Mime.Header.HeaderFieldParser.cleanMediaType(String mediaType)
>   at OpenPop.Mime.Header.HeaderFieldParser.ParseContentType(String
>   headerValue) at OpenPop.Mime.Header.MessageHeader.ParseHeader(String
>   headerName, String headerValue) at
>   OpenPop.Mime.Header.MessageHeader.ParseHeaders(NameValueCollection
>   headers) at
>   OpenPop.Mime.Header.MessageHeader..ctor(NameValueCollection headers,
>   IParsingErrorHandler parsingErrorHandler) at
>   OpenPop.Mime.Header.HeaderExtractor.ExtractHeadersAndBody(Byte[]
>   fullRawMessage, MessageHeader& headers, Byte[]& body,
>   IParsingErrorHandler parsingErrorHandler) at
>   OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart.ParseMultiPartBody(Byte[] rawBody) at
>   OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart.ParseBody(Byte[] rawBody) at
>   OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart..ctor(Byte[] rawBody, MessageHeader headers,
>   IParsingErrorHandler parsingErrorHandler) at

Openpop code is here

Exception throws from following class
[image]

***Question is***

How can I handle this exception?

Or Is there any New version of OpenPop with this fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is

> How can I handle this exception?

- Handling exception deos not needful, because I want to parse and download email. so I need to change code of OpenPop.dll's code.I downloaded code and with little bit of changes I am able to parse email

[image]

> Or Is there any New version of OpenPop with this fix?

- No I am using latest version.